# ros3djs Inverse kinematics

Tags: ros, kinematics, inverse, ros3djs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am new to ROS. I have a simple three link robotic arm, and I would like to find the inverse kinematics for the joint angles.

I already have the URDF. I want to click in a 3D space in the web browser widget and the end effector should point to that location.

Are there any tutorials on how to do this?

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244078/ros3djs-inverse-kinematics/) by [Kavita Krishnaswamy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28026/kavita-krishnaswamy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2017-02-18**:
You would like the end effector to reach that 3D space, or be pointing to it (outside of reach)? Both very different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt! is a popular choice for inverse kinematics. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ros_visualization/visualization_tutorial.html). The tutorials there will help you to configure a solver and use RViz for controlling your arm.

Once that's working, it's just a small step to use InteractiveMarkers in ros3djs to do the same from a web browser.

---

Originally posted by [T045T](https://answers.ros.org/users/5420/t045t/) with karma: 48 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0